# base64 string too long and image loads slowly (React, Node, MongoDB)

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, mongodb

Before the user signs up, they must upload a profile picture. The picture is in base64 format and the string is way too long. This image is not stored in MongoDB, just as a string in the user profile. Then I use the `<img>` tag to display it. It loads slowly. Is it because the string is too long?

Also, there is no code on the backend. I just handle the image upload on the client side, this base64 string gets stored in the object of the User, then I can display it with that really long string in the `<img>` tag.

The good practice would be if I handle the image upload on the server and store the image itself in the database? Do I have to use Multer for this?

[See here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6nJFm.png)

Part of signup:

```
user = new User({
            name,
            email,
            password,
            date,
            age,
            bio,
            gender,
            location,
            file: req.path.file,
            previewUrl,
            image: req.path.file,
        });
```

Part of User Schema:

```
image: {
        type: String,
    },
    file: {
        type: String,
    },
    previewUrl: {
        type: String,
    },
```

Client (React):

```
<input
    id="image"
    type="file"
    accept=".jpg, .png, .jpeg"
    onChange={this.pickedHandler}
    value={''}
    name="image"
/>

componentDidUpdate() {
        if (!this.state.file) {
            return;
        }
        const fileReader = new FileReader();
        fileReader.onload = () => {
            this.setState({ previewUrl: fileReader.result });
        };
        fileReader.readAsDataURL(this.state.file);
    }

    pickedHandler = (event) => {
        if (event.target.files && event.target.files.length === 1) {
            const pickedFile = event.target.files[0];
            this.setState({ file: pickedFile });
        }
    };
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a multi-layered question. But first:

- Why would you *not* store the profile image on your database? If a user visits the site on a different computer, they won't have their profile picture and would need to update it again. Unless you have a specific business rule as to why this is, I'd say save it on the dB.

React doesn't have any problem saving long strings or big data sets, so I don't see why this would be a problem from that point of view.

If you have a truly gigantic base:64, that'll cause issues, at least on rendering. base:64 is not meant to be used in this way, you should instead save the file itself and render it like a normal image.

Once you're saving it in the db, you won't need to use a base:64, and your problem should go away if you're using a simple `img` tag to render it as a url.

Good read about [base:64 for images](https://bunnycdn.com/blog/why-optimizing-your-images-with-base64-is-almost-always-a-bad-idea/#:~:text=To%20put%20it%20simply%2C%20Base64,database%2C%20CSS%20files%20or%20HTML.)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. According to this video, I successfully implemented the image handling on the cloud + displaying to the user. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YR4roPyfDQU&t ALSO, if anyone needs to know how to bind the uploaded image to a user who is signing up, let me know, I can help.